# How to calculate number of days by two dates in SSRS formula field

Tags: asp.net, datetime, date, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report and I have a table there, in which I have a column named as No. Of Days which are lying between two dates. I am getting those dates (datetime) through datasource but don't know how to calculate number of days between these two dates in a tablix cell formula.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following will get the difference between two dates:

```
=DateDiff("d","01-Jun-2011","10-Jun-2011")
```

which results in 9.

In a table cell it will be something like:

```
=DateDiff("d",YourDataSet.Fields!FirstDate.Value, YourDataSet.Fields!SecondDate.Value)
```