# Counting the duration of each item transection by condition of I(received[Date]), P(issue[Date]

Tags: reporting-services, counting

```
ITEM A        5-19-2014 1:46:54 PM  P
              5-20-2014 9:41:15 AM  I

ITEM B        5-14-2014 11:06:31 AM P
              5-14-2014 2:34:48 PM  I
              5-20-2014 10:23:50 AM P
              5-21-2014 11:59:00 AM I
              5-23-2014 12:00:00 AM I
              5-26-2014 9:34:50 AM  I
```

as per the records above, I need to use SSRS to count each Item duration with P and I condition. e.g the ITEM A. there shld have a total duration of 1 day show on the SSRS report

```
5-20-2014 9:41:15 AM - 5-19-2014 1:46:54 PM = 1 day
```

I'm new in SSRS. Can anyone advice me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try use expression to get Date Difference                                         =DateDiff("d","01-Jun-2011","10-Jun-2011") or refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6492081/3198474